# Combine both checkbox to know if they clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selection

I would like to know how do I `combine` the below two `checkboxes` to know `both` have been checked and I want to write their values in a `hidden field`.

These are my checkboxes and a hidden field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkText" id="cbA" value="" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="chkText" id="cbB" value="B" />B
<input id="TextSelection" type="hidden" />
```

I want to know something can be written like this as this is not working

```
if ($('#cbA','#cbB').is('checked')) {
$('#TextSelection').val("A and B");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hxUf3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write in the longer form:

```
if ($('#cbA').is(':checked') && $('#cbB').is(':checked')){
    $('#TextSelection').val("A and B");
}
```

[Simplified, working, JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hxUf3/1/).

#### Originally-posted, non-working, jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='chkTextEffects']").change(function() {
        if ($("#cbSolid").val() == 'Solid') {
            alert('Solid');
        } else if ($("cbOutline").val() == 'Outline') {
            alert('Outline');
        } else if ($('#cbSolid').is(':checked') && $('#cbOutline').is(':checked')) {
            alert('SolidOutline');
        } else {
            aler('No Effects');
        }
    });
});
```

The reason that your code, as posted, wasn't working is the order of the `if`/`else if` statements.

If *both* checkboxes are checked the this meets the requirement of the *first* of the `if` assessments; JavaScript doesn't assess whether there's another `if` that could be *more* true, it simply executes what it finds following the *first* assessment which returns `true`.

To keep the structure in that order you could add `&& $(otherCheckbox).not(':checked')`, but that's overly verbose. All you have to do is move the most-difficult-to-satisfy assessment ahead of the others that can be matched under multiple scenarios.

Comment: @David-First thanks for your reply.Updated with my demo as with your solution I tried it but don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: Check the edit, I've added a demo that works. I'll update again in a moment, to address why yours didn't.

Comment: @DavidThomas No Effects is not getting alerted when none is selected :P

Comment: @David-Thanks for the reasoning. Got it :)

Comment: In response to your previous comment: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hxUf3/3/).

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('#cbA').is(':checked') && $('#cbB').is(':checked')) {
    $('#TextSelection').val("A and B");
}
```

Another approach:

```
if ($('#cbA,#cbB').filter(':checked').length==2) {
  $('#TextSelection').val("A and B");
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHcJC/1/) of the second approach in action.

Comment: i think you mean #cbA in one of those selectors?

Comment: @John-First thanks for your reply.Updated with my demo as with your solution I tried it but don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, tweaking this as I test it. Try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Try new function `checkedResult` which will return as you select,

```
$.fn.checkedResult = function() {
    var result = '';
    $.each($(this), function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            result += this.value;
        }
    });

    return (result == '')?'No Effects': result;
};

var $chkboxes = $("input[name='chkTextEffects']");
$chkboxes.change(function() {
    alert($chkboxes.checkedResult());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hxUf3/2/)

---

Either write it in longer form like in other answers or write a custom function and return the `&&` of the result.

```
$.fn.isChecked = function () {
    var isChecked = true;
    $.each($(this), function() {
        isChecked = isChecked && this.checked;
    });

    return isChecked;
};
```

And then call it as below,

```
$('input[name=chkText]').isChecked()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/5juEk/)

Comment: @vega-I dont want to be triggered on the button click as I have tried earlier with that and would like to trigger when I click them and add those values to the hidden field.

Comment: That was just an example @vega. You should be able to apply the approach to your own solution.

Comment: @coder Updated code and demo and wrote a different version. Check the updated post and demo http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hxUf3/2/. Move the same code inside If you don't like it as an external function.